# Replace all arguments (of all strings) that exist in a dict with .format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if there is any pythonic way of replacing all arguments (of all strings) that exist in a dictionary with .format. For example:

```
dictionary = {"name": "{name_user}", "age": 26, "infos": [ {"name": "{name_user}" }]}
information = {"name_user": "Joao"}
```

Different from the following:

```
dictionary["name"] = dictionary["name"].format(**information)
dictionary["infos"][0]["name"] = dictionary["infos"][0]["name"].format(**information)
```

I wonder if there is any more efficient way to do this.

Note: the dictionary would be a JSON file

Comment: The resolution of this problem is in https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/452125/20273

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this

```
information = {"name_user": "Joao"}
dictionary = {
     "name": information.get("name_user", ""), 
     "age": 26, 
     "infos": [ 
        {
          "name": information.get("name_user", "") 
        }]
}
```

I don't know if it is most efficient way but I think is more simple way.

Comment: This is a good solution, but my dictionary is a JSON file! I'm sorry for not making this clear in the question.